# How to persist SSRS forms authentication ticket between pages in application

Tags: forms, authentication, reporting-services

I have implemented the SSRS 2005 custom security extension for external report use, however I am having some difficulty with the logon user session functionality.

I log on to the report server in .aspx code behind and get the report list because I have to add parameters into the report that the user can't see. The issue I have come into is when the user views the report and wants to go back to the report list page, the user get's an "Auth ticket was not received" error.

I can get around this if I just log the user into the report server on every page load/reload, but am wary of that approach. The reportserver class that comes with the custom sample doesn't seem to have a forms authentication credential property I can set or get.

Is there a way to log in once to the report server and persist the user's session between requests? If so, How?

Below is some of my code

```
Dim cookie As HttpCookie

Public Property ReportServer() As ReportServerProxy
    Get
        Dim _reportServer As ReportServerProxy

        If Not ViewState("rptServer") Is Nothing Then
            _reportServer = ViewState("rptServer")
        Else
            _reportServer = New ReportServerProxy()
        End If
        Return _reportServer
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ReportServerProxy)
        ViewState("rptServer") = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    cookie = Request.Cookies("sqlAuthCookie")

    'If Not IsPostBack Then
    GetReports()
    'End If
End Sub

Protected Sub GetReports()
    Dim passwordVerified As Boolean = False

    Using server As ReportServerProxy = Me.ReportServer
        Try
            ' Set the report server and log in.
            server.Url = AuthenticationUtilities.GetReportServerUrl("svrname")

            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' this is where my problem is!
            '///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            server.LogonUser("username", "password", Nothing)


            passwordVerified = True
        Catch
            Throw New Exception("An error occured while trying to access the report. Please contact website support for further assistance.")
        End Try

        If passwordVerified = True Then
            Dim items As Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.CatalogItem() = server.ListChildren("/", True)

            ' Add select option to ddl.
            ddlReports.Items.Add(New ListItem("-- Select A Report --", ""))

            'Get all report links that user has available.
            For Each cItem As Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.CatalogItem In items
                If cItem.Type = Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.ItemTypeEnum.Report Then

                    Dim lItem As New ListItem()
                    lItem.Text = cItem.Name
                    lItem.Value = cItem.Path
                    ddlReports.Items.Add(lItem)

                End If
            Next
        Else
        End If

        Me.ReportServer = server
    End Using
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlReports_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlReports.SelectedIndexChanged
    ReportViewer1.Visible = False

    If cookie Is Nothing Then
        '************************************************//
        '************************************************//
        '              NEED TO CHANGE URL BELOW!   
        '************************************************//
        '************************************************//

        'Response.Redirect("/appFolder/logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.RawUrl));
        Dim ex As New Exception("An error occured while trying to view the report. Please contact the website administrator for further assistance.")
        Throw ex
    ElseIf Not cookie Is Nothing And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlReports.SelectedValue) Then
        'Establish connection with reporting server, verify credentials and pull report.
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ssrsRptSvr").ToString())
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = ddlReports.SelectedValue

        'Set SSRS report credentials.
        Dim authCookie As New Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value)
        authCookie.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DomainName").ToString()
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = New RptServerCreds(authCookie)

        'Add account id or company parameter to report.
        Dim parms As New List(Of Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter)()

        parms.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("AccountId", MySession.AccountID, False))
        parms.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("GroupId", "2", False))

        Me.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parms)
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh()
        ReportViewer1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting the returned auth by using the below method. There is a COM method which sets the auth token to internet explorer. Reference System.runtime.interopservices.

```
  <DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
      Public Shared Function InternetSetCookie(lpszUrl As String, _
      lpszCookieName As String, lpszCookieDataAs String) As Boolean
     End Function
```